# How to set the height of browser window when it loads first time using jQuery or java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to set the height of browser window when it loads first time using jQuery or java script.
I want to set browser window height like 400px when i will open index.html page first time.Please tell me how to do ???

Answer (score 1):

On modern browsers, you cannot change the height of the window in the normal case. You can sometimes set the height of new windows you open via `window.open` (although there are limitations on that, mostly around the minimum size), but not the user's main UI window containing the browser's tabs. The height of that window is for the user to decide, not the web pages he/she visits.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the size of the current window directly. But you can change the size of any window opened using `window.open` method. To change the height/width, you can use the `window.resizeTo(width, height)` function. This will only work for the popup windows though..